# how is cardinality of free ultrafilters to be understood

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filters

Let $X$ be an infinite set, $F$ the set of filters and $U$ the set of free ultrafilters on $X$.
Then for the cardinalities we have $|U| \leq |F| \leq 2^{2^{|X|}}$. I have found several proofs
that we have equality throughout. But I don't understand them. So please give an explaination
of this fact.

The powerset of $X$ consists of pairs of set and its complement. A free ultrafilter contains
either the set or its complement. So the number of combinations is the binomial coefficient
of $2^{|X|} $ over $2^{|X| - 1}$ which equals $\frac{2^{|X|}!}{2^{|X| - 1}! \times 2^{|X| - 1}!}$.
How do I use cardinal arithmetic to show that this equals $2^{2^{|X|}}$? Or is this line of thought
not leading anywhere?

Comment: $$\huge\color{red}{\textbf{Cardinals are not real numbers.}}$$

Comment: If you have already found several proofs and understand none of them, what makes you think that asking for another proof here will produce one you understand? It might be more productive for you to point to a proof you didn't understand, explain *precisely* what you didn't understand about it, and ask people to help clear up your confusion.

Comment: @Alex: I don't want a new proof but an explaination how e.g. the free ultrafilters achieve the cardinality of the powerset of the powerset. This means that subtracting the finite sets  which cannot be members of the ultrafilter are of smaller cardinality and thus the leftover still has full cardinality.

Comment: @glurks Honest question: what is the difference between a proof and an explanation?

Comment: @Alex: quoting from the "The Ultra Series"(https://risingentropy.com/the-ultra-series-guide): Assumed background knowledge: basic set theory lingo (∅, singleton, subset, power set, cardinality), what is first order logic (structures, universes, and interpretations), what are ℕ and ℝ, what’s the difference between countable and uncountable infinities, and what “continuum many” means.